# How to load the javascript file in html (php) file

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

So I have little bit html on the footer.php and I cannot load the javascript files

Footer.php

```
        <footer>
            Test
        </footer>
        <script src="./assets/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
        <script src="./assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
        <script src="./assets/js/npm.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="./assets/js/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So when I see on the network on the browser I see the four js files is load like type html.

[image]

I used the Eclipse for PHP developers. 
How can I make the javascript files is load like javascript files not like html files.

When is load is have the mistake for every js file.

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

**Edit**: Index.php I not have any logic.

Index.php

```
    <?php 
    include 'views/elements/header.php';
?>

<?php 
    include 'views/elements/footer.php';
?>
```

In header I don't have any php or html code

**EDIT:**

I find my problem is in .htaccess. This is my .htaccess file and when I delete then is working.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUIEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUIEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

could some one tells me how can make .htaccess to working correct. Or some link from where can I see how to configurate the .htaccess file.

Comment: You should use `htaccess` for it to hide the file extensions or change it.

Comment: show the related php code ..

Comment: Looks like your web server is sending the wrong header information. The server should send `content-type:text/javascript`. Have a look at your server configuration.

Comment: @maxhb I used localhost with xampp. From which file I can check this information?

Comment: @evelikov If you hav not changed the xamp setup (which should be ok) then you should look out for a `.htaccess` file in your current document root.

Comment: I like to have a link to your page. Wamp does not need any configuration for javascript. Can you forward your router and give the IP? Or can you give me a copy of the script to look at it?

Comment: @Paules which script. I'm not have any logic. I just try to add jquery and bootstrap js on the the new web project. And I don't know but I cannot. I try and on another computer is have the same problem

Comment: I solve the half of problem thanks for every one for the help. Now is need to make good .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the .htaccess i use on my site to redirect all /tds/tre to the index except when called url is a directory or file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?syst=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: The reason why yours is not working is. you have miss spelled {REQUIEST_FILENAME} it should be {REQUEST_FILENAME}. Difference between your htaccess and mine. Mine htaccess does also cast the url after the / to the php code with $_GET['syst']